# "How long is the tomorrow meeting" or "How long is the meeting tomorrow"?

Tags: questions

Which of the following is, or are, correct to say?

1. How long is the tomorrow meeting expected to last?
2. How long is the meeting tomorrow expected to last?

Answer (score 4):

The second way is correct:

How long is the meeting tomorrow expected to last?

Alternatively: How long is tomorrow's meeting expected to last?

Answer (score 1):

The second, or "how long is the meeting going to last tomorrow?"